# latest version of pip that supports config flag

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-16.04

On a box that is limited to what distros it can get to. One of the things I'm trying to install requires using `pip -config` but I can't seem to find the minimum version that is supported.

I'm currently on `pip 9.0.3` and it looks like my distro is limited to these versions I can upgrade to:

```
(from versions: 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 6.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2, 8.0.3, 8.1.0, 8.1.1, 8.1.2, 9.0.0, 9.0.1, 9.0.2, 9.0.3, 10.0.0b1, 10.0.0b2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip config` CLI was added in 10.0.0b1 (2018-03-31).

See pull request [Add a configuration command #4240](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4240) and the [changelog entry](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#b1-2018-03-31).